# Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String'

Tags: string, powershell

I'm trying to establish a connection to a remote server that is not on Domain environment.
When running the Set-Item alone on PowerShell console without the script it works for some reason on the script it doesn't.

```
$passwd = convertto-securestring -String <Password> -AsPlainText -Force 
$cred = New-Object -Typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "developer", $passwd
$server = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your server IP'

Set-Item wsman:\localhost\client\TrustedHosts -Value $server -Force

$session = new-pssession -computername $server -credential $cred
```

When I run the above code, I receive the message

> Set-Item : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type
> 'System.String' required by the parameter. Specified method is not supported.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you are passing the input here, it should be a string value and a single object, if there is a comma or something, then the `$server` no more remains as string. 
To do a forceful conversion, you can convert the `$server` explicitly to String type by type casting:

```
[String]$server = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your server IP'
```

Further,

I would like you to hardcode the server name in the `Set-Item` and see if you are getting the error. You will not get it mostly.

```
Set-Item wsman:\localhost\client\TrustedHosts -Value 'YourServerHostname' -Force
```

So, validate while taking the input that what kind of input you are getting.